# journald is not logging error messages

Tags: linux, redhat, systemd, syslog

I'm having an issue wherein journald is not logging any error messages, but syslog seems to capture them just fine. Here's an example:

journald output:

```
msg=Publish internal=true prefix="mqi (mqi)"
coral.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

syslog (/var/log/messages) output:

```
app: time="Nov 24 00:26:24.379" level=info msg=Publish internal=true prefix="mqi (mqi)"
systemd: coral.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
app: panic: process queue name is too long 'ENV_SGOBSIDTESTMANTLEIDENTITIIIO_I8CDDI8CDD_PROC'
app: goroutine 28 [running]:
app: lab.identitii.com/identitii/lib/ibis/ibiscon/mqi.partyToQueueName(0xc4253e45d0, 0x1369fe8, 0xc42004f180)
    <stack trace>
```

The unit file for the service looks like this.

```
    [Unit]
    Description=Frontend
    Wants=network-online.target
    After=network.target network-online.target

    [Service]
    User=user
    WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/identitii/coral
    Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2
    Environment=I8_config_path=/usr/local/srv/config/common,/usr/local/srv/config/coral
    ExecStart=/usr/local/srv/coral/app 
    Type=simple

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've tried redirecting stderr to stdout by appending 2>&1 to the ExecStart with no love. Any ideas?

I'm running RHEL 7.2.

Cheers

Comment: This looks like a known issue. Does anybody have a workaround?

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2913